# How to add a gls fixed variance structure to a GAM

Tags: variance, heteroscedasticity, generalized-additive-model

I am using GAM to fit a smooth line to represent the recovery of timber stocks following forest harvest. The data is heterogenous and I do not want to transform it. I understand that a nice way to accommodate the heterogeneity in my data is to add a fixed variance structure.

However, when I try this in GAM I get the following error message:
"Error in model.frame.default(formula = t ~ 1 + age, weights = varFixed(~age),  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for '(weights)')"

I don't understand why the variable lengths would differ since I am using 'age' for specifying both the fixed variance structure and also the explanatory variable. Have a look:
M1<- gam(t~s(age), method = 'REML', weights = varFixed(~age))

Any suggestions would be welcome!

[image: The image is just to demonstrate heterogenous data that should be conveniently fixed with the varFixed()]

Comment: Here is an update: I could be wrong but I think that a variance structure cannot be added to GAM. It must be added to GAMM along with a random effect.

Comment: do you mind pointing to the example data you are using?

Comment: Also a couple of thoughts: the `nlme` function `varFixed` is a structure which depends on other aspects of the fitting procedure, so must be computed in tandem with a model. This makes it possible for `varFixed` to supply a fixed vector of weights, the type of argument `model.matrix` requires, giving the error you print. When you say "fixed" variance, I do not know if you mean *constant* variance, or if you are trying to set the dispersion to a constant in a generalized linear model (which would require other fitting methods than least squares).

Answer (score 3):

Now I know!

To add in a variance function (ie one from a generalized least squares; see Ch4 Zurr et al 2009) you must specify the model using GAMM.

However, note that in GAMM you can only add a variance function if using a normal probability distribution. This is because GAMM is simply a wrapper function (think of it as a control panel) that acts on other functions hidden within/behind it. If using a normal probabiltiy distribution then GAMM calls lme() and you can specify a variance function.

Once you change to a different probability distribution, then GAMM calls GLMM.PQL, which does not take variance functions (at least as far as I know).